# How to get TeamCity to run tests using MSTest?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, teamcity, mstest

I am trying to figure out how to make TeamCity run my MSTests.  I have setup a build step using the following parameters:

- **Path to MSTest.exe:** %system.MSTest.10.0%
- **List assembly files:** Projects\Metadude.*.Tests\bin\Debug\Metadude.*.Test.dll
- **MSTest run configuration file:** Local.testsettings

However when this step runs, it does not execute any tests.  This is the output from the log:

```
[02:13:49]: Step 2/2: Run Unit Tests (MSTest)
[02:13:49]: [Step 2/2] Starting: "D:\Program Files (x86)\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe" #TeamCityImplicit
[02:13:49]: [Step 2/2] in directory: D:\Program Files (x86)\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1f82da3df0f560b6
[02:13:50]: [Step 2/2] Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 10.0.30319.1
[02:13:50]: [Step 2/2] Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[02:13:50]: [Step 2/2]
[02:13:50]: [Step 2/2] Please specify tests to run, or specify the /publish switch to publish results.
[02:13:50]: [Step 2/2] For switch syntax, type "MSTest /help"
[02:13:50]: [Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1
[02:13:50]: Publishing internal artifacts
[02:13:50]: [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[02:13:50]: Build finished
```

I have tried to specify the tests to run using the following:

- **Tests:** Tests.Metadude.Core.Extensions.StringExtensionsTests

But that doesn't work.  I can't seem to find any documentation on google related to the MSTest build step in TeamCity.

**UPDATE**
Ok, I am an idiot.  Well that might be a little harsh, but the test assembly was missing an "s" from the assembly name.  Would have been nice to get something to that effect in the build log though.

Comment: @Leslie Hanks Which of the steps in the answer solved your issue?

Comment: @wal Well I had a typo in my assembly name.

Comment: I am also an idiot that missed a "s" from the assembly name. It's worth triple checking :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firstly, Ensure the assembly you are trying to test exists at that location.

ie

your relative path:
 Projects\Metadude..Tests\bin\Debug\Metadude..Test.dll

However I would expect something logged by TC if your file didnt exist. It looks like its running `MSTest` without any arguments somehow.

If you are sure the path is correct try it without specifying the `.testsettings` file to see what happens. I'm using MSTest succesfully in TC without this (but you may need it). The other thing I'm doing different is I specify the FULL path to `MSTest.exe`, ie

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe

instead of their variable `'%system.MSTest.10.0%'`

I can't recall why I did this but there would have been a good reason (like it didnt work when using their variable)

Comment: _Firstly, Ensure the assembly you are trying to test exists at that location._

As with @wal, it was the assembly name that got me. In my case the assembly name differed from the project name... assumptions. BTW: Nothing else gets logged by TC/MSTest.

Comment: Since Visual Studio 2012 (at least the express versions) MsTest.exe is called `vstest.console.exe` and can be found at

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe`

Comment: TeamCity is smart and full path to mstest.exe is not needed.

Comment: @qub1n at least 16 people disagree ??

Comment: Anyway it works for me (TeamCity 8.1.3). MStest.exe in windows cmd is not recognized, but Teamcity just work with only MSTEST.EXE. I have installed Windows 7 SDK + Build Tools.

Comment: If you don't want to install visual studio, you can install visual studio test agent, vstest.console.exe is found in the same path.